# How can Manager see their own customers in yii2 using RBAC

Tags: yii2, rbac

I have this a customer table where I have customername, address and salesmanagername. 
The invoice data is stored in another table - invoice, where I have Invoice details,customername.
I have a relation between customer.customername and invoice.customername.
I have a user table through which users log in. SalesManager's fullname is stored in the user table.
My query is SalesManager can view his customer related data only when he logs in.
I am using RBAC with DbManager & Yii framework. I've created a module,model and crud application - 
It shows invoice details for all the customers along with the respective salesmanager name.
I want SalesManager to see only data related to him.
Please let me know if any more information needed.
I've read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html but couldn't make it out.
Please help.

Here is my Bills Model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\salebills\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "bills".
 *
 * @property string $billid
 * @property integer $bills_ebillid
 * @property string $bills_year
 * @property string $console
 * @property string $billno
 * @property string $billdate
 * @property string $bills_partyname
 * @property integer $billamount
 * @property string $pdate1
 * @property integer $payment1
 * @property string $details1
 * @property string $pdate2
 * @property integer $payment2
 * @property string $details2
 * @property string $pdate3
 * @property integer $payment3
 * @property string $details3
 * @property string $pdate4
 * @property integer $payment4
 * @property string $details4
 * @property integer $totalpayment
 * @property integer $bills_tc
 * @property integer $bills_tc_approval
 * @property integer $doctorsgift
 * @property integer $mrcommision
 * @property string $mrname
 * @property integer $bills_other
 * @property string $bills_specify_other
 * @property integer $bills_other_approval
 * @property integer $overdue
 * @property string $cst
 * @property string $wbst
 * @property integer $caseno
 * @property string $amount
 * @property string $discount
 * @property string $tot
 * @property string $surcharge
 * @property string $total
 * @property string $tax
 * @property string $mrpvalue
 * @property string $cstpercent
 * @property string $wbstpercent
 * @property string $surpercent
 * @property string $totpercent
 * @property string $transport
 *
 * @property Parties $billsPartyname
 * @property Productsales[] $productsales
 */
class Bills extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'bills';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['bills_ebillid'], 'required'],
            [['bills_ebillid', 'billamount', 'payment1', 'payment2', 'payment3', 'payment4', 'totalpayment', 'bills_tc', 'bills_tc_approval', 'doctorsgift', 'mrcommision', 'bills_other', 'bills_other_approval', 'overdue', 'caseno'], 'integer'],
            [['billdate', 'pdate1', 'pdate2', 'pdate3', 'pdate4'], 'safe'],
            [['mrname', 'bills_specify_other'], 'string'],
            [['bills_year'], 'string', 'max' => 8],
            [['console', 'cstpercent', 'wbstpercent', 'surpercent', 'totpercent'], 'string', 'max' => 6],
            [['billno'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['bills_partyname'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['details1', 'details2', 'details3', 'details4'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['cst', 'wbst', 'amount', 'discount', 'tot', 'surcharge', 'total', 'tax', 'mrpvalue'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['transport'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['bills_ebillid'], 'unique']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'billid' => 'Billid',
            'bills_ebillid' => 'Bills Ebillid',
            'bills_year' => 'Bills Year',
            'console' => 'Console',
            'billno' => 'Billno',
            'billdate' => 'Billdate',
            'bills_partyname' => 'Bills Partyname',
            'billamount' => 'Billamount',
            'pdate1' => 'Pdate1',
            'payment1' => 'Payment1',
            'details1' => 'Details1',
            'pdate2' => 'Pdate2',
            'payment2' => 'Payment2',
            'details2' => 'Details2',
            'pdate3' => 'Pdate3',
            'payment3' => 'Payment3',
            'details3' => 'Details3',
            'pdate4' => 'Pdate4',
            'payment4' => 'Payment4',
            'details4' => 'Details4',
            'totalpayment' => 'Totalpayment',
            'bills_tc' => 'Bills Tc',
            'bills_tc_approval' => 'Bills Tc Approval',
            'doctorsgift' => 'Doctorsgift',
            'mrcommision' => 'Mrcommision',
            'mrname' => 'Mrname',
            'bills_other' => 'Bills Other',
            'bills_specify_other' => 'Bills Specify Other',
            'bills_other_approval' => 'Bills Other Approval',
            'overdue' => 'Overdue',
            'cst' => 'Cst',
            'wbst' => 'Wbst',
            'caseno' => 'Caseno',
            'amount' => 'Amount',
            'discount' => 'Discount',
            'tot' => 'Tot',
            'surcharge' => 'Surcharge',
            'total' => 'Total',
            'tax' => 'Tax',
            'mrpvalue' => 'Mrpvalue',
            'cstpercent' => 'Cstpercent',
            'wbstpercent' => 'Wbstpercent',
            'surpercent' => 'Surpercent',
            'totpercent' => 'Totpercent',
            'transport' => 'Transport',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getBillsPartyname()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Parties::className(), ['parties_partyname' => 'bills_partyname']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductsales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productsales::className(), ['productsales_ebillid' => 'bills_ebillid']);
    }
}
```

Here is my BillsSearch Model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\salebills\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\salebills\models\Bills;

/**
 * BillsSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\salebills\models\Bills`.
 */
class BillsSearch extends Bills
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['billid', 'bills_ebillid', 'billamount', 'payment1', 'payment2', 'payment3', 'payment4', 'totalpayment', 'bills_tc', 'bills_tc_approval', 'doctorsgift', 'mrcommision', 'bills_other', 'bills_other_approval', 'overdue', 'caseno'], 'integer'],
            [['bills_year', 'console', 'billno', 'billdate', 'bills_partyname', 'pdate1', 'details1', 'pdate2', 'details2', 'pdate3', 'details3', 'pdate4', 'details4', 'mrname', 'bills_specify_other', 'cst', 'wbst', 'amount', 'discount', 'tot', 'surcharge', 'total', 'tax', 'mrpvalue', 'cstpercent', 'wbstpercent', 'surpercent', 'totpercent', 'transport'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Bills::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'billid' => $this->billid,
            'bills_ebillid' => $this->bills_ebillid,
            'billdate' => $this->billdate,
            'billamount' => $this->billamount,
            'pdate1' => $this->pdate1,
            'payment1' => $this->payment1,
            'pdate2' => $this->pdate2,
            'payment2' => $this->payment2,
            'pdate3' => $this->pdate3,
            'payment3' => $this->payment3,
            'pdate4' => $this->pdate4,
            'payment4' => $this->payment4,
            'totalpayment' => $this->totalpayment,
            'bills_tc' => $this->bills_tc,
            'bills_tc_approval' => $this->bills_tc_approval,
            'doctorsgift' => $this->doctorsgift,
            'mrcommision' => $this->mrcommision,
            'bills_other' => $this->bills_other,
            'bills_other_approval' => $this->bills_other_approval,
            'overdue' => $this->overdue,
            'caseno' => $this->caseno,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'bills_year', $this->bills_year])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'console', $this->console])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'billno', $this->billno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'bills_partyname', $this->bills_partyname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details1', $this->details1])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details2', $this->details2])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details3', $this->details3])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'details4', $this->details4])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mrname', $this->mrname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'bills_specify_other', $this->bills_specify_other])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'cst', $this->cst])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'wbst', $this->wbst])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'amount', $this->amount])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'discount', $this->discount])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tot', $this->tot])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surcharge', $this->surcharge])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'total', $this->total])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tax', $this->tax])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mrpvalue', $this->mrpvalue])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'cstpercent', $this->cstpercent])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'wbstpercent', $this->wbstpercent])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surpercent', $this->surpercent])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'totpercent', $this->totpercent])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'transport', $this->transport]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Here is my Parties model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\salebills\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "parties".
 *
 * @property integer $party_id
 * @property string $parties_partyname
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $district
 * @property string $name_manager
 * @property string $transport
 * @property string $dlno
 * @property string $instruction
 *
 * @property Bills[] $bills
 * @property Productsales[] $productsales
 */
class Parties extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'parties';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['parties_partyname', 'district', 'name_manager'], 'required'],
            [['parties_partyname'], 'string', 'max' => 60],
            [['address', 'instruction'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['district'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['name_manager', 'transport', 'dlno'], 'string', 'max' => 30]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'party_id' => 'Party ID',
            'parties_partyname' => 'Parties Partyname',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'district' => 'District',
            'name_manager' => 'Name Manager',
            'transport' => 'Transport',
            'dlno' => 'Dlno',
            'instruction' => 'Instruction',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getBills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bills::className(), ['bills_partyname' => 'parties_partyname']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductsales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productsales::className(), ['productsales_partyname' => 'parties_partyname']);
    }
}
```

Here is my BillsController

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\salebills\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\salebills\models\Bills;
use frontend\modules\salebills\models\BillsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * BillsController implements the CRUD actions for Bills model.
 */
class BillsController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Bills models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new BillsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
       if ( Yii::$app->User->can('s_viewownsalebills')){
         $dataProvider->query->
             andWhere(['billsPartyname.name_manager'=> 'Bibekananda Acharya']);
        return $this->render('index', [
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
    }
   }
    //     return $this->render('index', [
    //         'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    //         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //     ]);
    // }

    /**
     * Displays a single Bills model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Bills model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Bills();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->billid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Bills model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->billid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Bills model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Bills model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return Bills the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Bills::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my updated actionindex

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        //$salesManager  = Yii::$app->user->identity->fullname;      
        $salesManageModel = User::find()->where(['fullname' => Yii::$app->user->identity->fullname])->one();
        $salesManager  = $salesManageModel->fullname;
        $searchModel = new BillsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
       if ( Yii::$app->User->can('s_viewownsalebills')){
         $dataProvider->query->
             andWhere(['billsPartyname.name_manager'=> $salesManager]);
        return $this->render('index', [
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
    }
   }
```

Here is my index file

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\salebills\models\BillsSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Bills';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="bills-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <!-- <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Bills', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p> -->

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'billid',
            //'bills_ebillid',
            //'bills_year',
            //'console',
            'billno',
            'billdate',
            'bills_partyname',
            'billamount',
            'billsPartyname.name_manager'
            // 'pdate1',
            // 'payment1',
            // 'details1',
            // 'pdate2',
            // 'payment2',
            // 'details2',
            // 'pdate3',
            // 'payment3',
            // 'details3',
            // 'pdate4',
            // 'payment4',
            // 'details4',
            // 'totalpayment',
            // 'bills_tc',
            // 'bills_tc_approval',
            // 'doctorsgift',
            // 'mrcommision',
            // 'mrname:ntext',
            // 'bills_other',
            // 'bills_specify_other:ntext',
            // 'bills_other_approval',
            // 'overdue',
            // 'cst',
            // 'wbst',
            // 'caseno',
            // 'amount',
            // 'discount',
            // 'tot',
            // 'surcharge',
            // 'total',
            // 'tax',
            // 'mrpvalue',
            // 'cstpercent',
            // 'wbstpercent',
            // 'surpercent',
            // 'totpercent',
            // 'transport',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permit to a SalesManager to  see only the data related to him  you can access to proper view (gridView) based on a dataProvider with a filter fixed on the SalesManager code ..

You can do this coupling teh RBAC functionality ( Yii::$app->User->can('SalesManager')) whit  a proper search function in ModelSearch ..
or simply adding a proper where condition to the dataProvider that retrive the sales ..

eg: in you action ... somethings like this

```
    $searchModel = new YourSalesSearch(); 
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    if ( Yii::$app->User->can('SalesManager') ){
          $dataProvider->query->
              andWhere(['your_sales_manager_key'=> $actual_sales_manager_code]);
         return $this->render('your_sales_manager_view', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
    }

    if ( Yii::$app->User->can('GeneralManager') ){
          // the general manager see all the sales of all the sales manager
         return $this->render('your_general_manager_view', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
    }
```

In you case you the indexAction could be

```
  public function actionIndex()
  {

      // You need the proper name for matching the name_manager 
      // If is the same of username you can use 
      $salesManager  = Yii::$app->user->identity->username
      // otherwhise you can find ........ whit proper
      // $salesManagerModel =  YourUserModel::find()->where(['your_column_name' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username])->one();
      // $salesManager  = $salesManagerModel->name;
      $searchModel = new BillsSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
     if ( Yii::$app->User->can('s_viewownsalebills')){
       $dataProvider->query->
           andWhere(['billsPartyname.name_manager'=>  $salesManager  ]);
      return $this->render('index', [
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  ]);
  }
```

and for the searchModel undefined you can try commenting in your gridView in index.php

```
   <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
```

or  add searchModel  in your render call  in actionIndex

```
           return $this->render('index', [
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'searchModel' = $searchModel,
  ]);
```

you havent't a join in BillsSearch for BillsPartyname
i think you should change this way

```
  .......

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1'); 
        $query->joinWith(['billsPartyname']);
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    .......
```

Comment: Not getting the $dataProvider->query-> andWhere (['your_sales_manager_key'=> $actual_sales_manager_code]); part. I have customer table where I have managername and cutomername. I have invoice table where I have customername and invoice details. There is a relation between customer.customername and invoice.customername.

Comment: The dataProvider is normally used if you want render a grdiview .. You instead want show data from model ?

Comment: What you are asking whit the last comment is not related to RBAC but how at your relation .. between model/table .. primarly seems an application design question ..once you have defined your function for relation wher you can apply the RBAC for use the proper function..

Comment: I've described my relation above. And I've added a image of the controller. You can see I am using the code you gave me. I've added the relation of my table in the image. Parties means customers.

Comment: But the relation between SalesManager and Customer via Bills How is made??

Comment: customername is common in both the customer table and invoice table and this has a relation as you can see. I have SalesManager in customer table. I do not have any option to link salesmanager to invoice table.

Comment: The question you are asking is in my opinion  too complex and is actually made up of more questions. First you have to find a way to be able to otter the data you wish to view with no problems of access based on the role you .. then you will face the questio of the role. I therefore propose to break down your question in simpler and specific questions .. and post them separately

Comment: Ok. I understand. I'll do that

Comment: I've edited the question. Tried to break it up and pin point the query. Please have a look.

Comment: I have looked at your edit question  .. in this you say  referring to you module "  It shows invoice details for all the customers along with the respective salesmanager name."  please can you provide the model and modelSearch and eventually the controllerAction  code where you show these data .. because i'm not able to undertand your  effettive relations between data .. And please no image .. instead edit question post and format properly the code ..

Comment: Well , parties is the related model for SalesManager ? .. I see in your bills controller  you have already a where fo selecting (in the sampe code is a fidex value)  the bills of   a salesManager ... please confirm ..

Comment: Yes. You are Right. And the salesManager in the parties table should be equal to the fullname of the user in the user table.

Comment: When I'm using $salesManager  = Yii::$app->user->identity->fullname; I'm getting a blank screen. When I'm using $salesManageModel = User::findOne()->where(['fullname' => Yii::$app->user->identity->fullname]);
        $salesManager  = $salesManageModel->fullname; I'm getting error - Class 'frontend\modules\salebills\controllers\User' not found

Comment: You must use the proper model name for User  and the proper field name .. che for User Model and for fullname attribute..

Comment: I've created the User model in the same model folder. do I need to "use frontend\modules\salebills\models\User;"?

Comment: Also I've added use frontend\modules\salebills\models\User; at the top of the page. Then I'm getting Missing argument 1 for yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::findOne(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\frontend\modules\salebills\controllers\BillsController.php

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. But still getting an empty page. I've given my present actionindex in the question. Please have a look. also I've added use frontend\modules\salebills\models\User; in the same page. Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: If you get an empty page but no error then   could be you have some problme with the value you get .. try var_dump($salesManager) or ($salesManagerModel) just before  the if so you can check if this vales contain what you need  for where ..

Comment: I was logged in with a user which didn't have any content. Now I've logged out from and logged in again with a user which should have a match(fullname) according to our search. Now I'm getting Undefined variable: searchModel - ( in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\frontend\modules\salebills\views\bills\index.php)

Comment: Well, we are almost there, you can try to remove (or comment on) the reference to searchModel in gridview index.php or even assign the searchModel variable to render call in the actionIndex

Comment: I'm not so sure how to do that. Can you show me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Getting 'Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'billsPartyname.name_manager' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bills` WHERE `billsPartyname`.`name_manager`='ManagerName''

Comment: This is related to you data model  .. check if you have the correct column name and the correct sintax in you function ..

Comment: Do I need to join the two tables? customers and invoice?

Comment: I repeat myself "you shoudl know your data model".. and another issue if  you now say "customers and invocie" but you show bills and parties .. for me  is impossible understand what are you doing ....

Comment: Ha ha. I am really sorry. It's bills and parties what I mean. You already have my bills model above. Please tell me what modification I need to make.

Comment: I've added this code in BillSearch Model. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry but the sql you show in the comment  : 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bills WHERE billsPartyname.name_manager='ManagerName'' how is realted with the dataProvider we are using .. seems part of another query .. is count and not select  .. sure you don't have other query in view .. ?

Comment: getBillsPartyname is the relationship between bills and parties - you can see it in the Bills model. apart from that there's another relation also but with productsales table and bills table - That also you can see in the Bills model.

Comment: I have  see the relation in model .. but the sql you posted in comment don't have the relation only a count(*)  for bills ... seem this don't is related to the code i expected for you billSearch model ..

Comment: The error is - 'Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'billsPartyname.name_manager' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bills` WHERE `billsPartyname`.`name_manager`='xyz'

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'billsPartyname.name_manager' in 'where clause'
)
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'billsPartyname.name_manager' in 'where clause'
in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php at line 840
'

Comment: I understand the error message infact if you look at the code in error you see select count(*) from bills ... instead you dataprovider should give you " select billid, ,,,,,, "  the error show in not related with the code call in actionIndex .. i think you have some other query in view  ..

Comment: You mean my index.php in the view folder?

Comment: yes. seems you have other query somewhere   with resulting code  select count(*) from bills..

Comment: I've added the index file in the question.

Comment: Somethings don't match:  in your actionIndex you don't have assigned searchModel in render Index  but in your gridview is assigned .. in this case the index view  should don't work ...

Comment: However seem the problem you have are not related to the question about RBAC but are related to rellation and query ..  i suggest you a deep study of this sample  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/ and try yourself to produce a gridview with filter on related value ..

Comment: I'll do that. Please tell me one point. Do this error has any relation with a column being 'index' in the database table?

Comment: not ... absolutly not .. the fact the column is an index is not a problem .. I think you are trying to solve a bit too complex problem in one shot ..Then . "dividi  et impera" split  the problem in more simple part  and after solved every single part  rebuild the complex one ..

Comment: Finally. We are done. As suggested by you http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/ I tried this. And found some real help from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/. Also in BillsSearch model changed billsPartyname.name_manager to parties.name_manager and there it is. I really thank you.